# Apache complains can't open port 443: No mention of 443 in httpd.conf

Tags: apache

I found apache not started today. It has been installed as a service on Windows 10 and was working fine until today. I am getting an `A service specific error occurred: 1.` error when attempting to `net start apache24`. When I try to start it manually, I get the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Which is funny, because there is no 443 anywhere in my httpd.conf. Weirdly, it gave me that error when port 80 until I changed it in httpd.conf. I changed the port to random other ones, it still says 443. I thought I had the correct httpd.conf:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64)
Server built:   Jul  1 2016 10:38:22
Distributed by: The Apache Haus
Compiled with:  Visual Studio 2015
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:61
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     WinNT
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     no
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses disabled)
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/Apache24"
 -D HTTPD_EXEC="/Apache24/bin/httpd.exe"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error.log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"

* The Apache Haus
* is not affiliated with, or endorsed by, the Apache Software Foundation.
* Apache HTTP Server, Apache, and the Apache feather logo are trademarks of
* The Apache Software Foundation.
```

But maybe I'm wrong?

Full httpd.conf:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e1a23e28efafbb2450f2245112a2d0e

Comment: Because of https://git.io/viJqN

Comment: Thanks, that helped